# Refactoring Conditional PHP

Tags: php, refactoring, conditional-statements

I'm wondering if there is another way to refactor my conditionals if/else statements. I feel I'm repeating the same thing over and over,

Here is a snippet (Keep in mind is wayyyy longer than that, but it follows the same principle) I could do a switch statement but it does not reduce the total code quantity.

I just want to get a second opinion of the best approach for this code to go into production. Also important to mention that the statements that I'm comparing $screen->id; are most likely to be dynamically generated if the user selects the checkbox, but that is outside of the scope of the question.

```
    //check admin screen
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen->id === 'topic') {

        $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/styles/tiny-mce-editor.css";
        $in['block_formats'] = $topics_blocks;
        return $in;
    }
    elseif ( $screen->id === 'provider-jobs')  {

        $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/styles/tiny-mce-editor.css";
        $in['block_formats'] = $providers_blocks;
        return $in;
    }
    //for all the page options
    else {

        $in['block_formats'] = $global_blocks;
        return $in;
    }

}
```

Thanks! Any guidance is appreciated.

**UPDATE!** Here is the refactored code, a little bit more cleaner! And complete so the whole context shows.

```
//check admin screen
$screen = get_current_screen();

//global ones
$in['block_formats'] = $global_blocks;
$in['toolbar1'] = $global_toolbar;

if ( $screen->id === 'topic') {
    $in['block_formats'] = $topics_blocks;
    $in['toolbar1'] = $topics_toolbar;

} elseif ( $screen->id === 'forum')  {
    $in['block_formats'] = $forums_blocks;
    $in['toolbar1'] = $forums_toolbar;

} elseif ( $screen->id === 'post')  {
    $in['block_formats'] = $blogs_blocks;
    $in['toolbar1'] = $blogs_toolbar;

} elseif ( $screen->id === 'jobs')  {
    $in['block_formats'] = $jobs_blocks;
    $in['toolbar1'] = $jobs_toolbar;

}
elseif ( $screen->id === 'provider-jobs')  {
    $in['block_formats'] = $providers_blocks;
    $in['toolbar1'] = $providers_toolbar;

}

return $in;
```

Comment: You may post this question on the [Code Review website](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (for reference: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/237701)).

Comment: i dont see a problem here

Comment: This may be on-topic for Code Review, as long as it **A** works, **B** isn't hypothetical or incomplete in any way. Please read the on-topic guide before posting.

Comment: The `else` is pretty redundant, you can go with just the `if` and `elseif` and then let the code just drop through to the `$in['block_formats'] = $global_blocks;
        return $in;`

Comment: "I could do a switch statement but it does not reduce the total code quantity." However, switch statements would make it more readable.

Comment: @vascowhite You are right ~ but in my context the switch case does not work! (just noticed). But it makes it more readable :)

Comment: Thank you for the replies! @Quill I will check out that reference provided and post in the correct forum next time!

Comment: The only thing I'd do is move the `return $in` out of the ifs, and place after.  If that's doable.

Comment: Possibly assign the global_blocks first, if that's the default.  And override later if necessary.  That would remove one if.

Comment: @progrock applied your solution and made the code a little bit cleaner. Will update question with new code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might register key/value pairs all known options/blocks. So your code becomes straight reduced, like this:

```
  $options = [
    'topic'         => $topics_blocks,
    'provider_jobs' => $providers_blocks,
    // ...
  ];
  //check admin screen
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  if (array_key_exists($screen->id, $options) {
    $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/styles/tiny-mce-editor.css";
    $in['block_formats'] = $options[$screen->id];
  } else {
    $in['block_formats'] = $global_blocks;
  }
  return $in;
```

---

**Edit, applies to the 2nd version of the OP**

Here the problem appears a bit different, so here is another solution:

```
$options = [
  'topic' => 'topics',
  'forum' => 'forums',
  'post'  => 'blogs',
  'jobs'  => 'jobs',
  'provider_jobs' => 'providers',
];
//check admin screen
$screen = get_current_screen();

//global ones
$in['block_formats'] = $global_blocks;
$in['toolbar1'] = $global_toolbar;
// variable ones
if (array_key_exists($screen->id, $options) {
  $in['block_formats'] = ${$options[$screen->id] . '_blocks'};
  $in['toolbar1'] = $options[$screen->id] . '_toolbar'};
}
return $in;
```

Comment: Woah!! thank you for this answer, this might be exactly what I'm looking for! Makes sense and it reduces the amount of code. Thank you! Will test shortly

Comment: Your answer is correct but it does not work in my case as I have two $variables for each of the conditionals. Whenever the condition is true I need to pass `$array_toolbar` and `$array_blocks` and in some instances even `$array_style`. To my knowledge, **keys** are unique. I can nest the variables in the same key as multidimensional arrays, but I think that unnecessary elevates the complexity!

Comment: @mmarquez So your given example was simplified. From your comment I can't totally get certainty about what are the additional variations, but I'm pretty sure it 'll be possible to adapt the solution without too much complexity. Please edit your question with all needed precisions, and I'll tell you what I think about.

Comment: @mmarquez Stop! Don't mind: I discovered your edit just after writing my above comment :) Let me examine it...

Comment: @mmarquez I edited my answer with a solution for your edited question. But I'm puzzled: it seems yet different from what you cited in your comment ?

Comment: I removed the $stylesVariable as it is not needed at this moment for this project! Sorry about that. Your solutions seems to make sense and I will apply to my code!! Thank you so much!! (untested for the moment)